# Configure mod_rewrite to add "www" and to support MVC

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to add **`www`** into the URL if the users forgot to type and still supporting MVC by redirecting to the `index.php` with `[QSA]`

This is my current working *.htaccess*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

> Using this *.htaccess* everything works fine, I can type `www.abc.com/xxx/yyy` to visit any specific pages

Anyway because I'm using Facebook authentication so I must prevent my users from typing the site URL without **`www`**, so I tried to edit my *.htaccess*

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wwww.abc.com/$1 [R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

> With this configuration if I typed `abc.com` I was redirected to `www.abc.com`, but if I typed `abc.com/xxx/yyy` I was only redirected as `www.abc.com` instead of being redirected to the specific page.

I also tried

```
# 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wwww.abc.com/$1 [QSA]

# 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wwww.abc.com/index.php [QSA]

# 3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wwww.abc.com/$1 [L,QSA]
```

None of them is working, please guide what to do

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this 2 lines above your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

so your final htaccess will look like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```